# execution timeout expired. the timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server not responding in C#

Tags: c#, python-3.x, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am calling python script from C#, In python script, we calling SQL procedure. When the user uploads the file containing 2.4 million records. It perfectly calling Python script from C#  and Then Python triggering the procedure and the data gets inserts the table successfully but the while returning the process again to C# it is showing the error execution timeout expired. the timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server not responding in C#

This was working fine past one year, suddenly showing this error to users but data getting inserted to DB successfully

I'm confused about why this occurring. Recently server ip is changed, I don't know this may cause any setting change in IIS or code issue

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "C:/Program Files/Python 3.5/python.exe";
    //startInfo.FileName = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python/python.exe";
    //startInfo.Arguments = "C:/PythonScripts/Test.py " + expat + " " + entity + " " + country;
    //startInfo.Arguments = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/PythonScripts/Test.py").ToString() + " " + expat + " " + entity + " " + country;

    startInfo.Arguments = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/File_Upload/PythonScripts/Test.py" + expat + " " + entity + " " + country; 

    startInfo.Verb = "runas";
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    bool t = process.Start();

    StreamReader myStreamReader = process.StandardError;
    string error = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

    StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
    string output = reader.ReadToEnd();

    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Close();
```

Python script  which calling from c#

```
 import pandas as pd
    import pyodbc
    import numpy as np
    import sys
    #import time   



    try:
            expat = (sys.argv[1])
            entity = ""
            country = ""
            if(sys.argv[1] == "Local"):
                entity = sys.argv[2]
                country = sys.argv[3]


            #start_time = time.time()
            df = pd.read_excel("C:\PythonScripts\TestPayBook.xlsx")
            #df = pd.read_excel("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\File_Upload_Wind_Auth\PythonScripts\TestPayBook.xlsx")

            server = 'xxxxxxxx' 
            database = 'xxxxxx' 
            username = 'xxxxxx' 
            password = 'xxxxxxxx'

            cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password+';TDS_Version=7.2;autocommit=False')
            cursor = cnxn.cursor()  
            if expat == "Local":

                entityList = entity.split(',');
                query = "select Mapping_Column, Source_Column from Tb_Payroll_ExcelMapping where country = '"+ country +"'  and [ENTITY] in (" + ','.join( ('\'' + x + '\'') for x in entityList) + ")"

                cursor.execute(query)
                rows = cursor.fetchall()

                ColumnMapping = {}
                for row in rows:
                    ColumnMapping[row.Mapping_Column] = row.Source_Column

                newColumns = {}

                columns = list(df.columns.values)

                for x in columns:
                    if x in ColumnMapping:
                        newColumns[x] = ColumnMapping[x]

                df = df.rename(columns = newColumns) 

            values = {'EXIT DATE': '1900-01-01', 'DATE OF JOINING': '9999-01-01', 'DOB': '1900-01-01'}
            df = df.fillna(value=values)

            df1 = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

            df_melt = df1.melt(id_vars=['PAY YEAR','PAY MONTH','EMPLOYEE ID','NAME','COUNTRY','CATEGORY','GRADE','BAND','EXPAT/LOCAL',

                                    'GATP/NON GATP','DESIGNATION','LOCATION / ENTITY','GENDER',

                                    'DOB','AGE','DATE OF JOINING','TENURE','PRODUCT','COST CENTRE','EXIT STATUS',

                                    'EXIT DATE','EXIT REASON','CURRENCY','DEPARTMENT'])

            paymonthlist = df_melt.get("PAY MONTH").unique().tolist()
            payyearlist = df_melt.get("PAY YEAR").unique().tolist()
            paycountrylist = df_melt.get("COUNTRY").unique().tolist()
            paylocationlist = df_melt.get("LOCATION / ENTITY").unique().tolist()
            payexpatlist = df_melt.get("EXPAT/LOCAL").unique().tolist()


            cursor.fast_executemany = True 

            DeleteQuery = 'Delete from TB_PAYROLL_TRANS where [PAY MONTH] in ('+ ','.join( ('\'' + x + '\'') for x in paymonthlist) + ') and [PAY YEAR] in (' + ','.join(str(x) for x in payyearlist) + ') and COUNTRY in (' + ','.join( ('\'' + x + '\'') for x in paycountrylist) + ') and [LOCATION / ENTITY] in (' + ','.join( ('\'' + x + '\'') for x in paylocationlist) + ') and [EXPAT/LOCAL] in (' + ','.join( ('\'' + x + '\'') for x in payexpatlist) + ')'                 

            cursor.execute(DeleteQuery) 

            #print("DeleteQuery done")
            #print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))


            params = [tuple(x) for x in df_melt.values]

            BulkInsertQuery = '''Insert into TB_PAYROLL_TRANS_JUNC ([PAY YEAR], [PAY MONTH], [EMPLOYEE ID], NAME, COUNTRY, CATEGORY, GRADE, BAND, [EXPAT/LOCAL], [GATP/NON GATP] 
            ,DESIGNATION, [LOCATION / ENTITY], GENDER, DOB, AGE, [DATE OF JOINING], TENURE, PRODUCT, [COST CENTRE], [EXIT STATUS], [EXIT DATE], [EXIT REASON], CURRENCY,DEPARTMENT, variable, value )
            values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'''



            for i in range(0, len(params), 1000):
                    subTuple = tuple(params[i:i+1000])
                    cursor.executemany(BulkInsertQuery,subTuple)
                    #print("Insert done: ", end=" ")
                    #print(i)
                    #print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

            #cursor.executemany(BulkInsertQuery,params)     

            #print("Insert done")
            #print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

            cursor.execute("EXEC [TB_DATA_REPO].P_Payroll_Trans_Junction")

            cnxn.commit()


    except IOError:
            print('An error occured trying to upload the file.')



> execution timeout expired. the timeout period elapsed prior to
> completion of the operation or the server not responding in C#
```

Comment: please add your python script

Comment: Solution found..We need to  increase Timelimit to sql server Connection. in c#. while calling sql server connection from c# default timing is 30secs

Comment: I am glad that you solve your issue with your self.
I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.
Thank you for understanding.